# Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com' | Could not resolve 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, repository, ubuntu-9.10

I am using ubuntu karmic koala. When I first logged in the sources.list file had an outdated list of repositories and so packages couldnot be reached. So I updated the sources.list to

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main  restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main  restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main  restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
```

After this i could perform the update and could get the packages using synaptic manager. But now suddenly both the synaptic manager and command line tools throw the error

```
Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'  
Could not resolve 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'
```

Could this be a temporary issue with the server? (But ping to the server gives back responses). Pls come one tell me what the issue could me...

Comment: Solved it! I am using VM for unix and there was some issue with the network connection in VM. Once it got reset everything is fine now.

Comment: @Vijay, as this question is localised, please consider deleting it.